# Contour Integral of $\oint_{|z|=3}\log(z-6)\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Here's my approach:

- I put $(z-6)=re^{i\theta}$, so that $dz=rie^{i\theta}$; $r=3$ due to contour and $\theta \in[0,2\pi]$
- Thus my integral becomes
  $\oint_{|z|=3}(3i\log{3}e^{i\theta}-3\theta e^{i\theta}) \,d\theta$
- Then I use integration of by parts and apply limits to get final answer as $(3\log{3}-6\pi i)$
- But the correct answer is $0$, as the function is **Analytic** inside the contour

So kindly help me point out why I couldnt get $0$ as expected.

Comment: It is hard to know exactly what you did. You have both $\theta$ and $z$ in your integral.

Comment: A better idea would be to set $z=3e^{i\theta}$. That parameterizes the path for $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @robjohn Made edits

Comment: @robjohn Oh, so you are saying my substitution is not following the contour correctly?

Comment: The notation $\oint_{|z|=3}(3i\log{3}e^{i\theta}-3\theta e^{i\theta}) \,d\theta$ makes no sense; should be $\int_0^{2\pi}$. Anyway, the error is almost surely in the $(3i\log{3}e^{i\theta}-3\theta e^{i\theta}) $; how did you get that, exactly?

Comment: $z=6+re^{i\theta}$ is NOT a paramatrization of $|z|=3$. You should use $z=3e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich By using laws of Logarithms and then expanding. But I think I got my mistake, I started off with wrong substitution. Thanks anyways

Comment: @TitoEliatron Yeah thanks for pointing out

Comment: Your integral is still wrong. Do you know how to compute $\log(a+bi)$?

Comment: @robjohn No. Any suggestion for references will be appreciated

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem? If you are taking a course, then it would seem odd that the text or the instructor has not shown how to take the logarithm of a complex number. You could look at [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).

Comment: It might help to read [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: @robjohn Actually I am learning by self. Coachings are closed due pandemic, and I consider this forum to be the best community to seek help while diving into the beautiful world of Mathematics. So you see there might be some gaps.

Comment: It might be good to learn how to evaluate a function before trying to integrate it. Did you find out what the real and imaginary parts of $\log(a+bi)$ are?

Comment: @robjohn Yess.. $\frac{1}{2} \log {(a^2+b^2)}+iArg(a+bi)$

Comment: Yes. Now, plug $z=3e^{i\theta}$ into the integral.

Comment: @robjohn got it Sir, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127229/discussion-between---and-robjohn).